# C# Twitter API, use or not a wrapper?

Tags: c#, architecture, twitter

Should I be using a wrapper library for Twitter's API, or just build a library of my own?

My application only needs to connect to twitter to read status updates from other users, and it doesn't need to post updates, or send Twitter any kind of messages.

**Update** this application is very resource intensive, so every "small performance gain" now is a potential huge performance gain in the future. Also, from what I've read, [TweetSharp](http://tweetsharp.codeplex.com/) is going to be discontinued?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you can find an easy-to-use library which has already been well-tested by others, why would you want to spend time building that part yourself, when that time could be spent building your real app?

Just because you won't use *all* of the API doesn't make it worth building your own library, IMO. Don't reinvent the wheel :)

Comment: @Cicada Actually there is point making a wrapper with reduced functionality and it can be called **performance** or **optimization** - you can decrease the size of your app, decrease memory that is required, increase speed, the code can be cleaner (not so extensible probably, but cleaner).

Comment: It might be fun (and useful) to build a wrapper just to learn how to do it.  Of course if the final application is your goal, then Jon's advice is best.  However when I'm learning something, I have often found it beneficial to roll my own version.

Comment: @Nico: "Resource intensive" in what way? Most of the time in talking to Twitter will be waiting for the network. Have you benchmarked existing Twitter APIs and found them wanting? It would seem odd to decide to write your own library on performance grounds without measuring the alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Building a wrapper library for Twitter of your own is just reinventing the wheel. You can find a bunch of Twitter libraries [here](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/libraries).

Comment: Unfortunately the link is dead.

Comment: @JYelton Because it was almost seven years ago and at that time Twitter supported platform specific libraries. Now it has only one universal public API using REST/JSON, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on a variety of factors; one I want to call out is avoiding binding yourself to external dependencies beyond your control.

If you only touch the external API in a limited number of places then going straight is probably ok; if you are building a large codebase with many potential touch points then you'd definitely want to go via a wrapper.